# Pattern to find all alphanumeric except the word "www"

Tags: php, regex

I am using `[0-9_A-Za-z]` that matches all alphanumeric characters:

```
'http://<slug:[0-9_A-Za-z]+>.domain.com/' => 'user/view'
```

I need a regex to match this, but except the word `www`.

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities, but the best one depends on the use case. What are you trying to achieve? Show your code and you will get relevant help quicker.

Comment: http://<slug:[0-9_A-Za-z]+>.domain.com/' => 'user/view'

It should redirect to user/view if slug is given any string except www

Comment: Try `<slug:(?![0-9_A-Za-z]*www)[0-9_A-Za-z]+>` or `<slug:(?!\w*www)\w+>`, but probably you do not want to allow `www` right after `://`, then try `<slug:(?!www\.)\w+>`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, (?!\w*www)\w+ is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add a negative lookahead to restrict the word character class:

```
'http://<slug:(?!\w*www)\w+>.domain.com/' => 'user/view'
```

Note that `[0-9_A-Za-z]` matches the same chars as `\w`, so we may shorten the pattern a bit.

To fix it, `(?!\w*www)` negative lookahead will fail all matches where `www` appears after any 0+ word chars (`\w*`).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a second check, for example:

```
if (preg_match($pattern, $string) && 'www' !== $string) {
```